# i am unable to install stable_baseline3 in my remote instance in vscode. EnvironmentError is showing up while installing. I am unable to import PPO

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I have been trying to build a DRL BOT with PPO agent. I connected my remote instance in aws in my vscode.I was trying to install `stable_baseline3` but every time I try `EnvironmentError` shows up. `stable_baseline3` is required to import PPO, so non of my code works as agent is unable to predict or work.

My code was working perfectly fine locally, its a problem when it comes to instance.